# libvirt/kvm guest failing due issues in the ApparmorProfile

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, apparmor

Why is my guest failing to start / failing to attach a device with this apparmor profile error.

Start:

```
error: Failed to start domain c
error: internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-8763795d-f056-4373-9d57-3d3bad391e5a'
```

attach-device:

```
   error: Failed to attach device from disk.xml
   error: internal error: cannot update AppArmor profile 'libvirt-8763795d-f056-4373-9d57-3d3bad391e5a'
```

Where and what is this libvirt-8763795d-f056-4373-9d57-3d3bad391e5a thing?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case I had a filename that had characters that can't be mapped into apparmor rules that prevent the guest breaking out. In the logs I found:

```
virt-aa-helper: error: skipped restricted file
virt-aa-helper: error: invalid VM definition
```

Due to my file with the (this time rather obviously) broken name.

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
  <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/break,^*[]&quot;, foo&quot;me.qcow'/>
  <target dev='vdd' bus='virtio'/>
</disk>
```

There is a wiki page about [AppArmor in regard to libvirt/KVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibvirtApparmor#preview) which explains how to get to the logs and how to tweak configuration in those cases.

The page also covers more common cases like uncommon image paths and using qemu:commandline through libvirt.

*P.S. Please let me know if you think there is a common case missing on the wiki page so we can extend it together.*